# Facebook Graph API, Unable to post as a page due to permission issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-permissions

I have a facebook application, not yet submitted to FB for permission review.

The app is intended to allow user to post and reply to other people's post as their own administrated page.

Upon authorization, the application would request the following permission

- Publish action
- Publish Pages
- Manage Pages

I used my own account, with tester role in the app, to granted all requested permission and verified the result in permission is indeed there in my app settings for the application. I have also verified that my account is an administrator of the page I intend to reply as.

It all seems ok until I tried to post a reply to the API using the page token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/postid/comments
```

I receive an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200
    }
}
```

I can't think of any reason why the permission is missing. I understand that the three permissions need to be approved by Facebook eventually, but to get approval, I'd need to get my app up running for testing first. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you check it in Tools & Support->Graph API Explorer. Check whether you're able to post.

Comment: Using graph API explorer's token, I can. Using my own token, I can't. I did side-by-side permission compare between my app and graph api explorer, it appears the same.

Comment: Debug your access token if it really contains the permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ And, did't you really get a page access token via `/me/accounts`?

Comment: Check the access token that you generated using the code. Use the Access Token Debugger. Paste the token that you generated and click debug button. This will show the token details.  What are the scope values that you're passing to $params...$helper->getLoginUrl($params);